# guava contiguous range by a rule

Tags: java, guava

For example, is it possible to create a Range of even numbers in guava?
Something like:

```
Range.closed(0,10) //0,2,4,6,8,10
```

I understand that the line above will not produce the output needed, but something like this may be:

```
Range.closed(0,10, SomeFunctionInterface<Integer>);
```

where

```
 interface SomeFunctionInterface<T>{
      T computeNext(T first);
 }
```

Is it possible in guava? This is still a contiguous range, just that a certain rule is applied on it.

I am only interested in a guava solution.

Comment: "This is still a contiguous range, just that a certain rule is applied on it." Not true because it's a range of `Integer`s and 0 and 2, etc. are not contiguous `Integer` objects. If you were to create an `EvenInteger` type and a `DiscreteDomain<EvenInteger>` (note: don't do that), it could be a contiguous range of that type, I guess. Guava's `Range` expects there to be one canonical way of comparing each Java type you want to use with it and `ContiguousSet` expects one canonical `DiscreteDomain`.

Comment: @ColinD you made me re-think this and I think this is absolutely right.

Comment: From the javadoc: 'Ranges are *convex:* whenever two values are contained, all values in between them must also be contained. More formally, for any `c1 <= c2 <= c3` of type `C`, `r.contains(c1) && r.contains(c3)` implies `r.contains(c2)`. This means that a `Range<Integer>` can never be used to represent, say, "all prime numbers from 1 to 100."'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guava can support this if you compose two operations together. First, you create the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}. Then, you filter it.

To turn the `Range` into the intermediate, unfiltered set, create a [`ContiguousSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ContiguousSet.html#create%28com.google.common.collect.Range,%20com.google.common.collect.DiscreteDomain%29). To do so, you'll need a `DiscreteDomain`, which is basically the `SomeFunctionInterface` you've described. Since you're dealing with integers, you can use the built-in [`DiscreteDomain.integers()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/DiscreteDomain.html#integers%28%29).

To get from there to the set of only even numbers, you can write a `Predicate` and then pass it and the intermediate set to [`Sets.filter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#filter%28java.util.NavigableSet,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29).

Comment: FWIW, this gets you a `Set`, not a `Range`.

Comment: (And also FWIW, it's deliberately designed so you can't get a `Range`, for the reasons Colin discusses above.)

Comment: True, I twisted your question into something I could answer :) Out of curiosity, will you be able to get by with a `Set`? or perhaps with a `Predicate` constructed by composing the original `Range` (which itself implements `Predicate`) with an `isEven` predicate? Maybe the part of your system that expects a `Range` can be changed to work with one of those. (If not, we can try to give you some other suggestions if you'd like to fill in some more detail about your requirements.)

Comment: @ChrisPovirk thx, there are no requirements whatsoever :) It was just a curiosity. Actually I will accept this, since there is no way to do it. Not the answer I wanted, but close enough. Cheers!